# how does client sends parameters in post request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to simulate a post request, so that I can repeat the request and find out the errors, but here I take parameters of earlier request in a textarea, and params are json string, now I have to extract the params and then redirect to original url

How do I do that??
Json parser creates an error while trying to parse submitted parameters

> ```
> JSON::ParserError (795: unexpected token at
>
> '{"data":"[{\"bundles\":[{\"bloody_hell\":\"killer\"}]}]"
>
> "app_created_at":"2012-04-27 10:18:04", "action":"push",
>
> "first":"YES", "controller":"syncs"}'): json (1.7.1)
>
> lib/json/common.rb:149:in `parse'
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to escape `"` when you use `'`, delete the `\`.

Answer (score 1):

remove " around [], and add comma..

u can stringify json and u will see how u have to emulate it

```
JSON.stringify({data: [{a:1},{b:2}],c:4})
```

output

```
"{"data":[{"a":1},{"b":2}],"c":4}"
```